# Method for String Building in java

Tags: java, strings

I have written a custom method to use StringBuilder in java. My Requirement is to create a method which accepts any number of arguments of any type and return String by concatenating the arguments.

eg. msgBuilder("Hello ",0," how"," are"," you ",2.5) return "Hello 0 how are you 2.5"

Here is my java code. Please Someone review my code and suggest If I did anything is wrong or Can I use this further in my projects.

```
        public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args ){
                String msg = msgBuilder("Hello ",5," How ","are ","you");
                System.out.println(msg);
            }

            private static String msgBuilder(Object... params){
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(Object obj:params){
                    sb.append(obj);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]?

Comment: Some logging frameworks allow parameterized `String` formatting, have you checked if your logging framework of choice has it? Also, are you on Java 8?

Comment: Yes I am using java 8 and using apache4j Logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this in mind:

```
private static String msgBuilder(Object... params) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (params.length > 0) {
        sb.append(params[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < params.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(" ").append(params[i]);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The above version allows you not to hardcode the white space delimiting your tokens. Instead of saying

```
String msg = msgBuilder("Hello ", 5, " How ", "are ", "you");
```

you can say succintly

```
String msg = msgBuilder("Hello", 5, "How", "are", "you");
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

#### Your approach

As pointed out by the other answers, you are practically hard-coding whitespaces in your arguments, which can get non-standard easily, even in your example. Otherwise, the use of `StringBuilder` is sound, although it wouldn't deal nicely with a single `null` value - the `for-each` loop will fail as it implicitly tries to get an `Iterator` for it.

#### Java 8

An alternative is to rely on the stream-based processing that Java 8 offers:

```
private static String format(Object... values) {
    if (values == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return Arrays.stream(values)
                    .map(Objects::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

1. Construct a `Stream<Object>` from `values` using [`Arrays.stream(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-).
2. [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) each value using [`Objects.toString(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString-java.lang.Object-) as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
3. [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) the stream into a `String` by [`joining(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) them together.

Comment: Will it be as efficient as StringBuilder()

Comment: Yes, it uses the new [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class as the underlying implementation, which in turn uses a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

I just decompiled the below code in java version "1.8.0_73"
and found that compiler is automatically optimizing the code for strings

```
            String hello = "a" + "b" + "c" + " hello " + " world ";
            System.out.println("Hello World!!");

            String a="a";
            String b="b";
            String c="c";
            String d=a+b+c;
            System.out.println(d);  
            System.out.println(a +" yo "+ b);
```

Code after decompiling

```
            String s = "abc hello  world ";
            System.out.println("Hello World!!");
            String s1 = "a";
            String s2 = "b";
            String s3 = "c";
            String s4 = (new StringBuilder()).append(s1).append(s2).append(s3).toString();
            System.out.println(s4);
            System.out.println((new StringBuilder()).append(s1).append(" yo ").append(s2).toString());
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  This may be insightful, but how does it relate to the question?  I.e. what changes in the posted code would you make?

Comment: As per my understanding, the query asked was to create strings in an optimize way.  e.g. while printing logs we append too many strings using +.
So above method was appending the strings using StringBuilder()

But when I decompiled the code the java compiler was doing this optimzation itself.

Answer (score 1):

@coderodde has a good point about eliminating the need for white space.

I'd simply do it this way:

```
private static String buildString(Object... values) {
        if (values.length == 0) {
             return "";
        }
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object value : values) {
            result.append(' ').append(value);
        }
        return result.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Nice Suggestion. Thanx!